# Update a React Element with the Data of Another Component's API Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http

I am trying to make a simple react app that pulls info from a MySQL database ("username", "balance", "purchases").

So far, I've used node and react to pull from the database with an HTTP query and to display each element on the website.

I then created the API query for searching the database for all entries that start with what I've typed into the search bar.

The issue I'm running into is **how do I change the state of the elements that display the username, etc with the new filtered information from the API query?** The search bar and data elements are two separate components so I can't use the use effect hook natively.

I cant use the filter method because the database is huge and I've sent my query limit to 100.

Here's my code so far:

```
  PlayerData.js
    
import axios from 'axios';
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';

    
const Player = () => {
  const [playerData,setPlayerData]=useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((res)=>{
    console.log(res.data)
    setPlayerData(res.data)
    })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
      })
  },[])

    return (
      <>
      {playerData.map((data,id)=>{
        return <div className="Player" key={id}>
          <span className="Username"> { data.name }  </span> 
          <span className="Crystals"> { data.balance }  </span> 
          <span className="DateModi"> {Object.keys(JSON.parse(data.items)).length}  </span>
        </div>
      })}
  
      </>

    )
};

export default Player;
```

---

```
SearchBar.js


import { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

const Search = () => {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("")
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/getSearchName/${searchTerm}`).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res.data)
    })
    return (
        <div className="Search">
   
          <input className = "InputField" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username:" onChange={e => {setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}}/>
          <span className="SearchButton" onClick={console.log(searchTerm)}>
                Search
            </span>

    </div>
    )
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you need to set the state of `PlayerData` to a shared component(`App`), and pass it to the `Player.js` component. Then when searching it will be overwritten and update the information in the `Player.js`

```
function App() {
  const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () =>
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/api/get")
      .then((res) => {
        setPlayerData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  const handleSearch = (text) => {
    const clearText = text.trim();
    if (!clearText.length) {
      fetchData();
      return;
    }
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3001/api/getSearchName/${clearText}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setPlayerData(res.data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Search handleSearch={handleSearch} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Player playerData={playerData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Search.js

```
const Search = ({ handleSearch }) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="Search">
      <input
        className="InputField"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Username:"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <span className="SearchButton" onClick={() => handleSearch(searchTerm)}>
        Search
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Player.js

```
const Player = ({ playerData }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {playerData?.length ? (
        playerData.map((data, id) => {
          return (
            <div className="Player" key={id}>
              <span className="Username"> {data.name} </span>
              <span className="Crystals"> {data.balance} </span>
              <span className="DateModi">
                {" "}
                {Object.keys(JSON.parse(data.items)).length}{" "}
              </span>
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```